# Show that there exist a $c$ such that: $ f(c) = g(c)\int_{a}^{c} f(t)dt$.

Tags: real-analysis

$f,g: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are two continuous functions such that $\int_a^b f(t)dt = 0 $

1. Show that there exist a $c$ such that: $ f(c) = g(c)\int_{a}^{c} f(t)dt$.

I don't see how to use the mean value theorem to prove that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Were you instructed to use the mean value theorem? Also, what does $f(d)dt$ mean?

Comment: @Cocomos No, I was instructed to use it. $\int_a^b f(t)dt = F(b) - F(a)$.

Comment: @Winther Ah! I'm sorry, I thought he asked if I was asked to use the mean value theorem to solve this. I did not pay attention to the typo. Thanks!

Comment: @Cocomos I made a mistake typing. I have just edited it. sorry.

Comment: Your problem statement is wrong. Take an $f$ such that $|f(t)| <1/2$, $f=0$ at only one point, and now pick $g=f$ and $b-a<1$. You get $1=|\int_a^c f(t) dt| \leq (c-a)/2 < 1/2$, which is impossible. You need to prove $$f(c)\int_a^c g(t) dt = g(c) \int_a^c f(t)dt.$$ This is the Cauchy Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @abnry If $f=g$ then there is a $c$ such that $f(c) = 0$ for which $f(c) = g(c)\int_a^cf(t){\rm d}t$ holds. The statement is true.

Comment: Are there no restrictions on $g$?

Comment: @robjohn No, there are none.

Comment: @Winther, my bad, good point. I was sloppy dividing by zero.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the function $F(x) = G(x)\cdot\int_a^x f(t){\rm d}t$ for some differentiable function $G(x)$. This function has the property that $F(a) = F(b) = 0$ so by [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that

$$F'(c) = 0\implies G(c)\left[f(c) + \frac{G'(c)}{G(c)}\int_a^cf(t){\rm d}t\right] = 0$$

Choosing $G(x)$ such that $\frac{G'(x)}{G(x)} = -g(x)\implies G(x) = e^{-\int_a^xg(t){\rm d}t}$ then $G(x)\not=0$ and the result you are after follows from the equation above.